# Xampp Website for Smarthome is not working

Tags: php, html, xampp

I m trying to make a website for a Smarthome project but I don't get other devices on the network to connect to the website, it just doesn't load. I tried to reinstall Xampp but it didn't change anything, I also tried to reset all of the router settings, but again it didn't change anything.
I m already using the IP address on the other devices.

Does someone have an idea of what may be off or what I could change to get it working?

Right now I m only running the default dashboard website with apache so it's not an error on the website.
(Ports:80, 443)